# How can I define a val using another val in objects of Ocaml?

Tags: object, ocaml

```
class my_object =
    object (self)
        val a = (* a lot of computation *)
        val b = (* use the result of a *)
    end
```

For this snippet in Ocaml, I know I can do this in a method, like defining b as mutable and compute it in a method. But it is not a concise way because I need to call that method somewhere. Can I do this in a better way?

Comment: Do you actually need classes? Or could you get away with ordinary functions creating objects? In my experience there are very few scenarios where classes are beneficial. I myself have never used them in any serious development.

Comment: Of course even with classes you could just write a builder function that precomputes the value, but that's significantly more awkward with classes that are expected to be created with `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define local variables between the `class` declaration and the `object` definition, as in

```ml
class my_object =
  let my_a = (* a lot of computation *) in
  let my_b = (* uses my_a *) in
object(self)
  val a = my_a
  val b = my_b
end;;
```

Note that with such a definition, the evaluation of `my_a` and `my_b` will occur once, at the class definition itself. If you want to redo the computation for each instance (e.g. because it depends on mutable state), just add a unit parameter to the class:

```ml
class my_object () =
  let my_a = (* a lot of computation *) in
  let my_b = (* uses my_a *) in
object(self)
  val a = my_a
  val b = my_b
end;;
```

In that case, an instance will be created by `new my_object ()`. Of course, you can have any number and type of parameters (including ones that are useful for computing `a` or `b`) instead of `()`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to set the value of b in an initializer:

```
class my_object =
    object(self)
        val a = 14
        val mutable b = 0
        initializer b <- a + 10
    end
```

This avoids having to remember to call a method from somewhere outside the class.

You could also pre-calculate the values for `a` and `b` and specify them when creating new instances of the class. This would let them be immutable.